Launching an app with sudo on startup
Appears to be the same as: Launching an executable with sudo on startup - command not found
Or:
Startup script with sudo in Ubuntu 16.10
But neither of them work! And rc.local does not exist on my system.
Tried to run an app: “re-Link” from Startup Applications. Needs root privileges. Had success with:
x-terminal-emulator -e sudo re-link

But it prompts for password, obviously. Can this be avoided?
Tried putting:
ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/re-link

In /etc/sudoersand /etc/sudoers.d/<file> with visudo, but nothing appears to happen. Still prompts for password, or refuses to start. Depending on if sudo is in command or not.
Running: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

Do the answers in How can I execute command on startup (rc.local alternative) on Ubuntu 16.10 help?

No, did not work. Maybe the link should have been in the: “Appears to be the same as” list.
As mentioned, the file: /etc/rc.local did not exist on my system. And I understood this as, that it is no longer in use, and should not be attempted to use.
